# Sencha destroy view, recreate a new one with events

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a MVC style Sencha Touch App.

When I destroy a view with

```
view.destroy();
```

and then try to recreate the view with

```
view = Ext.create('testapp.view.view1');
```

All the connections to events in the controller no longer fire. What is the proper way to destroy a view & recreate it so the events will still link up and fire?

Comment: How are you setting up the listeners?

Comment: Can you update your question to include that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mitchell said - "Try not using the id config and let componentquery resolve a component using xtype and a property."

Check out this discussion: [Controller Action painted event not firing after destroy and re-creating panel](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?203620-Controller-Action-painted-event-not-firing-after-destroy-and-re-creating-panel)